# Apache .htaccess rewrite for mutiple pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a new script, I am using mod_rewrite to create permanent links. But I also want to have a login page that goes to a different main page.

ie.
http://www.example.com/dashboard
will load index.php
but
http://www.example.com/login will load login.php

currently my .htaccess looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Not sure the best way to do what I would like. Tried to look around and couldn't find this example.

Comment: Add a more specific rule for `^login$` before the other rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all You need is just .php rewrite, so that You can use php pages with or without .php extension. The rest (redirecting) You should do from php scripts.

Here is how .htaccess should look like in this case.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```